# Vue js Highmaps - How to load map?

Tags: highcharts, vue.js, highmaps

I'm kinda new to Vue.js but today I am trying to setup some sort of map to show data. I ended up picking Highmaps since it seemd like the best alternative of the bunch and also because I already used it (Highcharts) for other projects.
Now the problem arises because I am developing a component driven webapp but I want to import maps from Highmaps. Since they just use CDN paths I don't really know how to implement them by using the import statement. Below is some code to make you understand better.

```
--- main.js ---
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import MapComponent from './components/MapComponent.vue'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighMaps from '../node_modules/highcharts/highmaps.js'
import VueHighcharts from 'vue-highcharts'
import loadMap from 'highcharts/modules/map';

loadMap(Highcharts);

Vue.use(VueHighcharts, { Highcharts });
Vue.use(HighMaps);

Vue.component('app-map', MapComponent)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
------------------------
--- MapComponent.vue ---
<template>
  <div>
    <highmaps :options="chartOptions"></highmaps>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Element from 'element-ui';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import HighCharts from 'vue-highcharts';

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
          chartOptions: {
              chart: {
                  map: 'countries/it/it-all'
              },
              ... 
          }
    },
  }
</script>
```

[This is what you can see from the browser, the errors appear when I try to press the + / - or when I scroll inside the map's borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo4CD.png)

As you can see inside the script tag I already imported some libraries but I can't undestand how to import Highmaps too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I have found a way (probably cheesy) to force the map data into the map itself by copy pasting the object inside a variable and then referencing it into the chart.map

I understand that this is probably very bad since Vue needs to go and compile all of that object right inside the component but I hope it is a temporary solution.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <highmaps :options="chartOptions"></highmaps>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Element from 'element-ui';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import HighCharts from 'vue-highcharts';

  export default {
    data () {
    var country= {"title":"Italy","version":"1.1.2","type":"FeatureCollection","copyright":"Copyright...}
    return {
          chartOptions: {
            chart: {
              map: country
            },
    ...
    }
</script>
```

You can find the map data at [this](https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) url (choose the GeoJSON option)

## EDIT

I have finally found a good way of doing this by just saving the raw json data of the map into a local .json file and importing it as follows:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <highmaps :options="chartOptions"></highmaps>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HighCharts from 'vue-highcharts';
  import json from '../map.json'

  export default {
    data () {
      return {
          chartOptions: {
            chart: {
              map: json,
            },
            ...
      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see in the image you have an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError, HighCharts is not defined at ...

This is because, whenever you import a library for Vue, you should provide it as a component.

So, you have to add this:

```
import HighCharts from 'vue-highcharts';

export default {
   //...
  components: { HighCharts },
  //...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad, the image was a little bit old and some errors stuck event after having fixed them. I updated the image and, just to clarify, I already load all the components I need inside the main.js file, that's why you can see the outlines of the chart but not the actual image though. Still have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here it's that the CDN imports `VueHighcharts`, you can register it globally as

```
Vue.use(VueHighcharts, { Highcharts: Highcharts })
```

and then use it everywhere

```
<highmaps :options="options"></highmaps>
```

Take a look at the examples on the bottom of the [Lib Readme](https://github.com/weizhenye/vue-highcharts)

Also, it's better to install it via npm to have a better modular structure to work with webpack (or whatever you use)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and my bad for not making it clear that I already have imported and used all the components I need inside the main.js. Oh, and I use webpack and npm for everything, never wanted to include CDN's but since I can't find any good alternative...

Comment: npm i vue-highcharts -S

Comment: I did all the steps you provided but still the map won't show, any other idea? I think I should load a javascript file for that but I can't understand how.